# React TS onClick select input value

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a task to create simple controlled components for an input with typescript. The target of this component stores the value in the state and also, when clicking on the input, the text was selected. I am starting to work with typescript for the first time and do not know how to correctly implement the function for selecting text on click.

```
interface InputChangeInterface {
  target: HTMLInputElement;
}

type FieldProps = {
  type: string;
};

const TextField = ({ type }: FieldProps) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState('');

  const handleOnChange = (event: InputChangeInterface) => {
    setState(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSelect = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    // console.log(event.target);
  };

  return (
    <div className="input-group mb-3">
      <input
        type={type}
        value={state}
        className="form-control"
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onClick={handleSelect}
      />
      {state}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Give this page a look https://react-typescript-cheatsheet.netlify.app/docs/basic/getting-started/forms_and_events

Comment: @kunquan thanks, i will read. But can you help to write part of code about my issue ?

Comment: Maybe its good if you share live code or some error that you are facing. You question with some context around it will help others to help you better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
const handleSelectInput = (event: { target: { value: any }) => {
    event.target.select()
}
```

But you need to also add `value: {state}` to your `<input>`. So your code should be:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

interface InputChangeInterface {
  target: HTMLInputElement;
}

type FieldProps = {
  type: string
};

export const TextField = ({ type }: FieldProps) => {
  const [state, setState] = useState("");

  const handleOnChange = (event: InputChangeInterface) => {
    setState(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSelect = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    event.target.select();
  };

  return (
    <div className="input-group mb-3">
      <input
        type={type}
        value={state}
        className="form-control"
        onChange={handleOnChange}
        onClick={handleSelect}
      />
    </div>
  );
};
```

I tested on [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-waterfall-2krg5?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) and it works.

Comment: Can you try adding value={state} in your <input> please? Right now it doesn't seem like a controlled input.

Comment: Thanks, in sandbox work, but when i add to my project i get error `TS2339: Property 'select' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'`

Comment: It should work. You can try using `event: HTMLElementEvent<HTMLInputElement>` instead of `event: InputChangeInterface` but I think it should work if it works in sandbox.

Comment: `const element = event.currentTarget as HTMLInputElement; element.select();` so it worked thanks, in which case it makes sense to use ref?

Comment: It's for the use of mutable variables, [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) is the react documentation for useRef. Keep in mind though, that you should usually prefer not to use useRef hooks if not necessary (or at least not overuse them, as the React documentation states). Please upvote/accept answer(s) that helped you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useRef to select input value with react.

This is the example code you can look.
https://react-typescript-boilerplate-simple-vopcyi.stackblitz.io

```js
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import React from "react";

const App: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState("");
  const inputRef = React.useRef(null);

  const handleOnChange = (event: { target: { value: any } }) => {
    setState(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSelect = (_: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
    if (inputRef) {
      inputRef.current.select();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="input-group mb-3">
      <input
        type="text"
        className="form-control"
        value={state}
        ref={inputRef}
        onChange={handleOnChange}
      />
      <button onClick={handleSelect}> Select</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: thanks for core, but i get error TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'. for line 
``` inputRef.current.select(); ```

Comment: add null handler like this one
   if (inputRef) {
      inputRef.current.select();
    }